# How to configure time zone?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have the following problem in Ax 2009 with time zones:

I have a site in Europe (Spain), but with users operating in Mexico.

The time zone configured for users is that of Mexico City, users connect via Terminal Server to Ax, the server time is seven hours from Spain being more advanced (Mexico are 1 pm, in Spain is 8:00 pm)

The problem is occurring in the days change on a server in Spain.

If I go into Microsoft Dynamics AX menu, click Tools and then Options, shows me that the time zone is that of Mexico.
In Microsoft Dynamics AX menu, click Tools, and then click Date and time of the session, time shows me the session with Mexico time.

But when given the 5pm of Mexico in Spain already switch to be the next day, to change the date on the server also automatically changes my date in dynamics Ax and operations in Mexico are still the 5: 05 pm pm on October 31 I recorded transactions dated November 1 at 00:05 am, to name one example.

If I go into Microsoft Dynamics AX menu, click Tools, and then click Date and time of the session, when he shows me the session schedule for example Mexico is 5:05 pm.

Without anything to have occasion to modify the date and time window session give OK, then I update the date and time to the time zone of Mexico again.

What is this?, Is there a way around that by changing the date on the server for the change of day does not affect the configuration of the time zone set for users?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds exactly how it is supposed to work and your problem is that of your setup.  If I post something at `5:05pm` in Mexico it is simultaneously `00:05am` in Spain.  So when you change your timezone via `Tools>Options`, it will change the date because it is merely a display for the same point in time.

It sounds like your real issue is when events post to the ledger...specifically which day they post.  I believe this is because under `Basic>Setup>Company Information`, you have your company setup in Mexico time zone.  I think this time zone is what dictates what day/time everything rolls up in the end.

You should create a separate company, or if you're fine with everything posting in Spain time, then switch it there.